# How to reset the audio system?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I am using the logic from  [Android : Switching audio between Bluetooth and Phone Speaker is inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770321/android-switching-audio-between-bluetooth-and-phone-speaker-is-inconsistent) to switch output between earpiece, speaker, and bluetooth. Here is the code:

```
//For BT
mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
mAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
mAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);

//For phone ear piece
mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
mAudioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
mAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);

//For phone speaker(loadspeaker)
mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
mAudioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
mAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
mAudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

This logic works as expected as long as no other application has used audio (media player, phone, etc.). If I run my application after running the other application, the logic goes haywire. The audio still works except the destination output is not what is expected. For example, instead of speakerphone, the output may go to earpiece.

Note that I run my application after quitting from the other application. There is no overlap.

It appears audio manager settings are not specific to an application and may mess up other applications. I am wondering if there is a way to reset audio manager before setting my mode. Regards.

Comment: did you resolve it?

Comment: got any solution?