# How to cast audio to different device within flutter app?

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a podcast app with just_audio and audio_service packages. Since audio_service registers this audio within the operating system, I can select headphones from Control Center/Notification Bar. I need to cast this audio to speakers/headphones within the app. Is it possible to put that in the application?

Example from audible app from amazon.

[Audible screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsBXn.jpg)

[Audible screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtGYg.png)

Comment: Try audio_session which exposes the Android `AudioManager` and iOS `AVAudioSession` APIs. You can then find other answers on StackOverflow which deal with these two native APIs. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770321/android-switching-audio-between-bluetooth-and-phone-speaker-is-inconsistent .